# Linkedin SSO throws error "it was not possible to access the OAuth request token: it was returned an unexpected response status 404 Response"

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm working on linked in SSO login using php I using below the script. Instead of returning code in get method error throws.

"it was not possible to access the OAuth request token: it was returned an unexpected response status 404 Response."

[https://github.com/AmirMustafa/LinkedIn-API-Login-PHP/tree/master](https://stackoverflow.com)

[app scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7RL4.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3mId.jpg)